# How could a String contain all the StringBuilder result in Java

Tags: java, android, stringbuilder

i'm writing a code that get a Json String from the google geocode api , i'm using a StringBuilder to build the String from the Input stream that i have , well the problem is when 
the String that the StringBuilder Have is not the same that the Function StringBuilder.tostring(); returns ...

i have a code like this :

```
 sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                Log.i("line",line);
            }
```

this gonna show all the lines using Log.i("line",line); so well .. but when when i do :

```
sb.toString();
```

It only returns some of the String that i want ... any suggestions guys ?

Note : The Json Result of the API is so long . you can try with this one 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Hospital+Jijel

Comment: Log output has limitation. Write it to the file or debug to check out real data contained in StringBuilder.

Comment: Can you show us what you are expecting to be logged and what was actually logged?

Answer (score 2):

Writing to the log will truncate your string if it's too long, which in your case it probably is.

Write the contents of your `StringBuilder` to the screen or a file to see its full contents.